# Run event when any button from an array is called

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have a list of buttons that is grabbed using `document.getElementsByClassName`. I'm trying to check if any of them are pressed; It doesn't need identification. Just need to run a function if any of these buttons are pressed.

Any tips? I can't use jquery-I'm using tampermonkey for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jQuery, you should add click event listeners to all of your buttons you want to get notified.

Like this:

```
var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^=button]');
console.log("Found", allButtons.length, "div which class starts with “button”.");

for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
  allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log("You clicked:", this.innerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a forEach on the list you get from `document.getElementsByClassName`  and add an eventListener to each one.

For example

```
document.getElementsByClassName("exampleClassName").forEach(function(element) {
   element.addEventListener("click", function() {}))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ***wanted*** to use jQuery with Tampermonkey, all you need to do is add a line like this in the top `==UserScript==` section:

```
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js
```

*Of course, the link can be any link to a CDN-hosted jQuery*

For example:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         jeffreyprather.com
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        https://jeffreyprather.com/
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    //your code goes here

})();
```